# acf field repeater link don't work

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, links

I am trying to make an acf repeater field with the link field.
I don't understand why I get an error message:
**"Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in"**

**Here is my code**

``

```
    <?php if($assos):?>

    <?php foreach ($assos as $asso):
            
        $web = $asso ['title_fields_two'] ?>

        <span> 
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($web);?>">
                <?php echo "$web";?>
            </a>
        </span>

    <?php endforeach; endif?>``
```

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that `$web` is not a string but an array. [`esc_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) uses `ltrim()` on the value you pass to it. You'll have to check with ACF support for more on this; third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: ok i see thank you